# Shape traffic to certain speeds for a specific process

Tags: alpine-linux, bandwidth, traffic-shaping

I need to shape traffic for a specific PID to certain speeds. For example, I would like to limit upload for PID 7502 to 300Kb/s, and download for PID 7502 to 400Kb/s. How can this be done?

I have researched:

- iptables' limit module

  - only limits by number of packets
- `tc`

  - found unreliable and doesn't run on Alpine
- GNU trickle

  - requires target application to be integrated with RPC, which my process does not support

Are there any reasonable alternatives to these?

Comment: Use cgroups + netfilter hashlimit

Comment: Why you say that is not working in Alpine?